# How to make my carousel indicators interactive and move to the nth carousel item when the nth indicator is pressed?

Tags: bootstrap-4

So I just made my first carousel today and I stumbled upon this issue. My next and previous buttons work so I think there is no problem with my scripts. Thank so much in advance, even if you just looked through

Here is my code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="description-container">
<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
  <ol class="darken carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active container-fluid">
       <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 0!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
       <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 1!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
       <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 2!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
       <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 3!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
       <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 4!</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="darken carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a>
  <a class="darken carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're left/right indicators are connected to `testimonial-carousel`... while the individual indicators are connected to `myCarousel`... both should be the same as in the code snippet below:

```css
/* Make the image fully responsive */

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-item {
  background: lightblue;
  min-height: 200px
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
  <ol class="darken carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active container-fluid">
      <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 0!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
      <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 1!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
      <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 2!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
      <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 3!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
      <h4 class="testimonial-text">Me text 4!</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="darken carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a>
  <a class="darken carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks! All I did was change the data-target from "#myCarousel" to your "#testimonial-carousel"...thanks, I didn't realise that they were different but I do now thanks